# only let people login with special rank

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want that people only can login to a page with a rank of `>= 500`. (a register page I already have.) I already searched on this site very much for the answer but I couldn't find it.

index.php

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{

     ?>

    <h1>Member Area</h1>
     <p>Thanks for logging in! You are <b><?=$_SESSION['Username']?><b> and your email address is <b><?=$_SESSION['EmailAddress']?></b></p>


    <ul>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout.</a></li>
    </ul>

    <?php
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

     $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];


        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

        header("Location: index.php"); //Redirect
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
    }
}
else
{
    ?>
```

Is there any way I can do that?
I would appreciate some help.

Comment: What about saving the user rank and fetching the data accordingly using the check for rank ??

Comment: Have a key 'rank' in your database and use PHP to fetch rank and check it's above a certain threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If rank data is being stored in the `users` table, then modifying the query that authenticates the user as follows will do:

```
"SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE Username = '".$username."' 
    AND Password = '".$password."'
    AND Rank >= 500"
```

This is the general idea.

Wherever this data is being stored, you will be joining it with the username and (encrypted) password combination with your rank >= 500 condition, or any other condition you want fulfilled before allowing login.